# Limit of $\sqrt[2^{n}]{2^{n}-n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I need to find the limit of this expression:

$\sqrt[2^{n}]{2^{n}-n} = e^{\frac{1}{2^{n}}ln(2^{n}-n)} = e^{\frac{1}{2^{n}}[ln(2^{n}) + ln(1-\frac{n}{2^n})]} \implies e^{\frac{1}{2^{n}}ln(2^{n})} = \sqrt[2^{n}]{2^{n}} \implies 1$

Did I do it right?

Comment: And what is the limit *with respect to*??

Comment: I would suggest that you can calculate $lim \frac {ln(2^n-n)}{2^n}$ using L'hopitals rule directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $ 2^{n-1} < 2^n - n < 2^n, n \ge 2$.

Comment: The result will be the same as mine. Is my solution wrong?

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: And the transformations? I like your answer better because it was probably intended by the person that made that excercise to solve it that way. May I ask just how did you know about the left side of your inequality?

Comment: That one comes from $2^n > kn, k > 0, n $ large

Comment: And there are also other inequalities ilke this one involving $n!$ and $2^{n!}$, am I right? That is super useful in the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Could you tell me how to name that property (that some functions grow "faster" than others) so that I can find out more about that on google and make my squeeze theorem solutions more effective? If I had an inequality with the whole seqence of most useful functions that would be great.

Comment: Is that correct? $1<log_n<n<n^2<n^k< 2^n < n! < n^n< n^{n!}$ for $k \geq 2$

Comment: Exponentiate and use the squeeze theorem with $\leq$ instead of <?